# Delete 2 last commits, discard local changes, reset --hard vs checkout

Tags: git

Scenario: The two last commits are bad and must be deleted (local and remote). The working tree must come back to HEAD~2 overwriting current changes (let's assume it's OK or b/c they have been stashed). Also let's assume I am the only one working on the branch, and it's OK to delete remote commits.

What is the difference between:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~2
git push origin +HEAD
```

vs

```
git checkout HEAD~2
git push origin +HEAD
```

**Question2:** what is the recommended syntax (as of April 2017) for forcing a push of a diverging branch?

```
git push origin +HEAD
vs
git push origin MyBranchName --force
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git checkout HEAD~2` is for going to see how it was (by populating the working directory) at a certain commit in the past but without modifying the history. You are now it a detached head state (read about it because it is useful to know how to handle that).

`git reset --hard HEAD~2` is what you describe and what you want.

`git push origin --force-with-lease` is the way to go. 
That's the same than '--force' but with an added verification that you don't destroy history push by someone else that you did not see (you can't overwrite history that you won't have already fetched). That is definitely the way to go and should have been the default when you do '--force' but that is not the case, surely for compatibility...

Comment: The `checkout` command is confusing though. In some case it must be used to discard changes. For example: revert myFilename back from latest commit: `git checkout HEAD -- myFilename`. However `git reset --hard HEAD -- myFilename` is incorrect (fatal: Cannot do hard reset with paths)